# omap3530/3630 emulation on QEMU for overo and beagle machines

Tags: virtual-machine, embedded, virtualization, qemu

On QEMU's source code for beagle and overo I can see that the cpu emulated is the OMAP3430. I will like to know if it's a way to make QEMU emulate OMAP3530/3630 cpu's for those machines?

On bealge :

```
s->cpu = omap3_mpu_init(sysmem, cpu_model, ram_size,             
                                serial_hds[0], serial_hds[1], serial_hds[2], serial_hds[3]);
```

How do I have to set cpu_model?

On overo:

```
s->cpu = omap3_mpu_init(sysmem, omap3630, args->ram_size,
                            serial_hds[0], serial_hds[1], serial_hds[2], serial_hds[3]);
```

I changed omap3430 for omap3630 but I'm not sure that this will work.

I'm using QEMU 1.4.0 Ubuntu's 13.04 distribution. I guess that all the applicable patches for beagle and overo machines are included on that distribution. For what I have seen while looking in google about beagle and overo patches, I think that the patches are there.